# Loop echo CSS class by PHP

Tags: php, html, css

**CSS**

```
.number{
  float:none;
  background-color:white;
  cursor:ponter;
}
#panel{
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

I want to make a list of number in a panel. I've tried with HTML

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel>
  <span class="number">1</span>
  <span class="number">2</span>
  <span class="number">3</span>
  <span class="number">4</span>
  .....
  <span class="number">50</span>
</div>
```

When `<span>` is clicked, something will appear by jQuery, but I have no problem with jQuery.

Because I thought that looping the number manually doesn't efficient, I tried to use PHP.

**PHP**

```
<?php
for($number=0;$number<=50;$number++){
  echo "<span class='number'>".$number."</span>";
}
?>
```

But the number made by PHP doesnt do the same like HTML does.

This is what I want and done by HTML.

[image: This is what I want and done by HTML.]

This is done with PHP and the numbers are made horizontally until 50

[image: This is done with PHP and the numbers are made horizontally until 50]

Comment: there is a typo in your HTML (missing `"` after panel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the same whitespace is present when looping through it in PHP:

```
<?php
for($number=0;$number<=50;$number++){
  echo "<span class='number'>".$number."</span>\n";
}
?>
```

Remember, your original code is just outputting one long string:

```
<span class='number'>1</span><span class='number'>2</span>...
```

In this case, whitespace (A newline) is important which may alter how your CSS looks. Forcing a new line each time you echo out a `<span>` by adding `\n` should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

.number{ display : inline-block; }

Comment: Please, edit your code with a formatted code and a a brief explanation.